# Reduce cold boot time of Cloud functions by trimming dependencies

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In Cloud functions, trimming dependencies from package   .json is effective to reduce the cold boot time?
If the answer is yes, how about moving dependencies to devDependencies?

I'm using Cloud functions for Firebase, and it uploads files under functions folder without node_modules.

The node_modules directory in containers of cloud functions is automatically created by Cloud functions. 
So investigating whether the countermeasure (which is noted above) is effective or not is difficult.

Comment: You could always put the function into the app, less processing on your side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing dependencies from `package.json` might have a small effect on deploy time, but will not generally have an effect on cold start. Cold start is only affected by the packages that you *load* in your code, i.e. the number of `require()` statements that are needed to bootstrap your function.

It can be a good practice to require packages inside the function body if it is only used for one function. For instance:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.myFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const lib1 = require('lib1');
  const lib2 = require('lib2');

  res.send(lib1.callMethod(lib2.otherMethod()));
});
```

If you had other functions in the same file that were deployed by the Firebase CLI, they wouldn't load `lib1` and `lib2` since they are only required *inside* the function body.

Comment: Does moving the require to the function mean what’s required is loaded on each function trigger event?

Comment: I understood about lazy loading. I have another question, Isn’t the number of dependencies affect the time to launch an instance of cloud functions? I think each instance of cloud functions have node_modules, and the size of it will affect cold start.
Is cloud functions have node_modules outside the instances?

Comment: Probably shouldn't say anything as I'm sure Michael is much more familiar than I am. (He works at Google on this.) But, my experience matches what he says that the size of node_modules does not matter much. When your doing a cold start, the system transfers a zip of the package and loads the entry point from package.json as a module.  I'm sure there is some time in transferring the zip package to the server. I've seen no relationship between node_modules and startup time, but I do see a shift in time based upon how many modules are loaded in the package.

Comment: I just wanted to know why cold start is only affected by the packages that you load in your code, but questioning to the answer from Michael might be rude, sorry. BTW, I've investigated the impact of dependency which is not loaded on my code(I compared simple function with smallest dependency(87MB) and 45 dependencies(240MB)). From execution log of CF, both response time is around 90msec. From this result, the number of dependency is not affect the time of cold start.

Comment: Oh, it's not rude at all to want to understand more! Sorry if I came across  as suggesting that. I was more trying to defer to him. :-)

Comment: As to my understanding of why, package/module that are in node_modules aren't loaded until a 'require' is used to load them. (They're just sitting on disk.) When a cold start occurs, it loads your function/module which then loads all the other modules it needs. Since functions have a small amount of CPU dedicated to them, it can take a few seconds to run all the code in the utilized packages which is why you see the delay. Transferring the zip file and extracting it is a small % of that time, so the impact of having it on disk  is negligible in most cases.